# Alter Magento product codes in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, magento

I have just asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/330711/add-0s-to-values-in-column-in-excel) on SuperUser regarding Microsoft Excel. Thankfully someone answered - but then I realised that if I alter the SKU column and re-import the product CSV file it won't update the products. It would treat them as new products because the SKU codes don't match.

The question was:

I am trying to edit product codes in Excel so that each product code is exactly 8 digits in length.

Currently the product codes are different lengths, for example:

```
12
1222
213212
32
3231
3213131
```

The above codes should read as follows:

```
00000012
00001222
00213212
00000032
00003231
03213131
```

As you can see all product codes are now 8 digits in length, any product codes that were less than 8 have had the correct number of 0's prepended to them.

It's surprisingly easy in Excel- but is it possible to do it directly on the database tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MS SQL Server:

```
UPDATE
     Products
SET
    product_code = RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000', product_code), 8)
```

You just fill in a bunch of 0's at the start and then take the 8 right-most characters.

Comment: Its mySQL if that makes a difference?

Comment: MySQL also has the `RIGHT` function, but uses `CONCAT` (or possibly || depending on the version?) for concatenating strings. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The SKU codes are in a table called 'catalog_product_entity' and when I view that table and click SQL in phpmyadmin I get the following line:

SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE 1

Should I then add your code to the bottom of that?

Comment: Read through here on how to connect to the database and submit queries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Create the following PHP file and this should work.  I haven't had a chance to test it but I run mysql update scripts with something like this all the time for magento.

```
<?php

    // initialize Magento environment
    include_once "app/Mage.php";

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);        
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');     
    $sql1 = 'update `catalog_product_entity` set sku =  RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000', sku), 8)';     

    $connection->query($sql1);      

?>
```

Comment: I have added the above to a file called changeSKU.php, when I visit the URL it loads a blank screen and has no effect. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Still no joy. Could my server config be blocking it somehow?

Comment: check file permissions? or just run the update in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the SQL command I ran to get this working was:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `sku` =  RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000', sku), 8)
```